# Regex match between delimiters

Tags: java, regex, replace

I am trying to figure out a way to match domain name in a config file. My file may look like this:

```
<abc="xyz">abc.com</abc>
```

I want to match abc.com and replace it with placeholder text. My current Java solution was replacing exact domain in text by calling StrName.replace("abc.com","random")
However, it will also replace `abc.commmmm` with `randommmmm`. I don't want that. So, I tried regex. However, my regex `[.><](abc.com)[.<>]` will also select `> and <` in the string. I don't want that. I also realized that the text could be something like this:

```
<abc="xyz">text.abc.com.net</abc>
```

I still want to replace abc.com, so my regex won't work. How do I correct this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: Are you looking for [word boundaries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html)? As in `\b(abc\.com)\b`? (Edit: escape that dot!)

Comment: Try regex  [`(abc.com(?!m))`](https://regex101.com/r/TiGUKL/1)

Comment: @svasa What's that sorcery!?

Comment: `(?<=[.><])abc.com(?=[.><])` I'm unable to test this but give this a try it  uses positive lookbehind and positive lookahead

Comment: @svasa I think he might be after positive look(ahead|behind) rather than negative

Comment: @Isaac Doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @svasa It works, but I don't get it.

Comment: @Maxsteel you might be able to piece something together from these http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html I'm not sure of the support in java though

Comment: @MaxSteel, as I understand your requirement you don't want `abc.commm` but `abc.com`, that regex matches only if there are no extra `m`s , uses [`negative look ahead`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: @svasa I believe the extra `m`s was an example of something not to match, not the only thing to not match which is why negative look(ahead | behind) won't work. I suspect abc.combbbb would also be a match @Maxsteel would want to avoid

Comment: @svasa that wouldn't work as you'd get matches for `abc.com!!!` and `mmmmabc.com` and `abcdcom`

Comment: All of the comments about "but it'll also match" and "but it won't match" on this question and on gwcoderguy's answer are an indication that the _specification is insufficient_ – the problem statement is unclear. Are these statements correct? (a) match the literal string `abc.com` (b) only when it appears between `>` and `<` (c) other text can optionally also appear between `>` and `<` (d) but only letters and dots (d) what else? You can't write a regex unless you can define _exactly_ what you do _and don't_ want to match.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using positive look-ahead and positive look-behind in your regex. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Positive look-ahead is written like `THING1(?=THING2)` and it means find `THING1` followed by `THING2`.

Positive look-behind is written like `(?<=THING1)THING2` and it means find `THING2` followed by `THING1`

In both of these cases the `THING` within the lookahead will not be consumed. For your first example you could do something like: 
`(?<=>)abc\.com(?=<)`

meaning abc.com preceded by > from `(?<=>)` and followed by < from `(?=<)`.

If you are also looking to replace `abc.com` between periods as in text.abc.com.... you can try:

`(?<=[.><])abc\.com(?=[.><])`

meaning abc.com preceded by <,> or . from `(?<=[.><])` and followed by <,> or . from `(?=[.><])`.

This will give you  `<abc="xyz">random</abc>` and `<abc="xyz">text.random.net</abc>` for your two examples, as well as no match for `<abc="xyz">abc.commmm</abc>`

NOTE: escape the period by using `\.` instead of `.` otherwise you will match `abcdcom` as `.` matches any charachter. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Thanks, but <test>test.abc.com.common</test> should also give a match, and this wouldn't, right?

Comment: So you want to replace abc.com when it is preceded by a < or a . ? Otherwise, I'm not sure of the distinction between text.abc.com and abc.commm

Comment: adjusted to include for a abc.com between a period < or >

Answer (score 0):

Besides using look-arounds, you can do this with standard capturing groups.

First, define what you're looking for...

> Find `abc.com` when it appears within tags — enclosed within `>` and `<`
>   and optionally has additional dotted prefixes and/or suffixes.
>   Replace `abc.com` with `random` when found in these circumstances.

This looks to me like a multi-level domain with two or more segments, which `abc.com` must be a part of.

What are the parts we're looking for?

1. The fixed string **abc.com** – the re for that is `abc\.com` escaping the dot so it's a literal instead of "any character".
2. Optional domain parts *preceding* "abc.com" – letters followed by a dot `[a-z]+\.`
   ... but there can be zero *or more* of them, so `([a-z]+\.)*`
3. Optional domain parts *following* "abc.com" – a dot followed by letters, zero
   or more times `(\.[a-z]+)*`
4. All of that enclosed within the end of a start tag `>` and the start of an end tag `<` ... so `>something<`

Putting that all together we get `>([a-z]+\.)*abc\.com(\.[a-z]+)*<` which needs to be escaped to be a Java string `">([a-z]+\\.)*abc\\.com(\\.[a-z]+)*<"`

Now, since we are matching and consuming the `>` and `<` we'll need them in the replacement string, and we're *capturing* the prefix and suffix so we need to put those in the replacement also using the capturing groups 1 and 2, giving `>$1random$2<`

I put this *re* in at regexplanet.com http://fiddle.re/fxhfxn using these test strings and producing the replacement strings:

```
<abc="xyz">abc.com</abc>           =>  <abc="xyz">random</abc>
<abc="xyz">abc.commmmm</abc>       =>  <abc="xyz">abc.commmmm</abc>
<abc="xyz">text.abc.com.net</abc>  =>  <abc="xyz">text.random.net</abc>
[abc="xyz"]text.abc.com.net[/abc]  =>  [abc="xyz"]text.abc.com.net[/abc]    
<abc="xyz">abc-com</abc>           =>  <abc="xyz">abc-com</abc>
<abc="xyz">abc.com.fr</abc>        =>  <abc="xyz">random.fr</abc>
<abc="xyz">www.abc.com</abc>       =>  <abc="xyz">www.random</abc>
```